# Ruby Minitest using stub from different test

Tags: ruby, minitest

I'm trying to test a very (and non-logic) ruby class.

```
class Post
  attr_accessor :title
  def initialize
    @title = "Treehouse Blog"
  end
end

class Blog
  def create_and_get_title
    post = Post.new
    post.title
    if post.title == nil
      post2 = Post.new
      post2.title
    else
      post.title
    end
  end
end
```

and here are my tests:

```
require 'minitest/autorun'
require_relative 'blog'
require 'ostruct'

class TestBlog < Minitest::Test
  def setup
    @blog = Blog.new
  end

  def test_title_is_treehouse_blog
    assert_equal('Treehouse Blog', @blog.create_and_get_title)
  end

  def test_title_is_yyy
     def Post.new; OpenStruct.new(title: nil) end
     def Post.new; OpenStruct.new(title: 'yyy') end
    assert_equal('yyy, @blog.create_and_get_title)
  end
end
```

Simple, right? However I get the following output from running the tests:

```
 1) Failure:
TestBlog#test_title_is_treehouse [test.rb:12]:
Expected: "Treehouse Blog"
  Actual: "yyy"
```

I don't get the failure in every run, I just get it randomly, looks like the stubs are being cached or something.

Any ideas?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You have a syntax error in your `test_title_is_yyy` method in the `assert_equal` call. A quote is missing.

Answer (score 1):

The way you've implemented this, you're not actually stubbing the method but rather replacing it, and you'll get the same failure every time the `test_title_is_yyy` is run first.  The fix is to use `Object#stub` to replace the stubbed method only within the scope of a block as:

```
def test_title_is_yyy
  Post.stub(:new, OpenStruct.new(title: 'yyy')) do
    assert_equal('yyy, @blog.create_and_get_title)
  end
end
```

By the way, using `def` as a stub replacement is totally fine if you're stubbing instance methods.  You're stubbing a class method though, and since the class isn't reloaded between tests, you've redefined `new` for the remainder of the test run.